# Scala Slick 3.0 Update row whilst omitting db id

Tags: sql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm using Slick 3.1.1 and a case class to represent the mapping with an existing table and I'm trying to update a row. One way I found doing this is by specifying which fields to update like so:

```
val query = table.filter(_.id == id)
                 .map(r => (r.field1, r.field2))
                 .update(("value1", "value2"))
db.run(query)
```

The table has a few more fields. Now the problem is that the whole row comes into this method and some fields remain unchanged. I saw on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23994180/3029403) that in Slick 2.X the following was an option:

```
table.filter(_.id === id).update(row)
```

Trying the above however naturally produced a `Cannot update identity column 'id'` error.

Is there a way I can do an update without having to specify specific fields whilst at the same time leaving out the `id`?

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hey Pawel. It's MS SQL Server.

Comment: Slick itself allows presence of IDs during updates (after all it just converts our code to SQL queries) and your code would work fine if executed against e.g. PostgreSQL. I don't know much about MS SQL Server, but its `IDENTITY` property is the problem here. Would it be possible for you to define your primary keys without that property? You might check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17249583/4838717 for the details.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that might be the problem..I'll have a look at the post you suggested. Thanks Pawel!

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this issue?

Comment: @preston.m.price Unfortunately not. I ended up specifying the fields that were being updated.